# Typescript - enum - able to see " Enum declarations can only merge with namespace or other enum declarations. " error

Tags: typescript, enums

`Typescript .ts file contains the below code for enum type

```
enum dow  ``{
    Sunday,
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday
}`
```

Typescript to Javascript transpiled file code:

```
`var dow;
 (function (dow) `{
    dow[dow["Sunday"] = 0] = "Sunday";
    dow[dow["Monday"] = 1] = "Monday";
    dow[dow["Tuesday"] = 2] = "Tuesday";
    dow[dow["Wednesday"] = 3] = "Wednesday";
    dow[dow["Thursday"] = 4] = "Thursday";
    dow[dow["Friday"] = 5] = "Friday";
    dow[dow["Saturday"] = 6] = "Saturday";
}`)(dow || (dow = {}));`
```

`
In terminal after giving *tsc enumtype.ts*
able to see the error as*** Enum declarations can only merge with namespace or other enum declarations.***

Comment: What line of code is being pointed to with that error? Where else do you reference `dow`?

Comment: [Ln 4, Col 5] 'Dow' was also declared here. Enum declarations can only merge with namespace or other enum declarations.                                                                                   Dow I mentioned here as (Days Of Week) I'm referring to udemy course "Typescript for beginner by Bharath Thippireddy'